# Is there some graphical way to create my own configuration file on SonarLint?

Tags: c#, sonarlint

I downloaded the SonarLint code on Github and would like to try in the company projects that I work by analyzing existing code. I wonder how I could create a standard configuration file with the rules that I want to evaluate the solution to analyze the projects. Is there a practical example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you don't have to start from the source code, you can use the VSIX package from the [Visual Studio Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47d1049d-bb27-454e-aab8-24566c85e548). After installing it, just right click on the Project/References/Analyzers node in the Solution Explorer, and edit the active rule set file. SonarLint is using Roslyn, so enabling and disabling rules can be done in the standard integrated way in Visual Studio.