# Can I configure the used ruleset for SonarLint

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

Can I disable / enable the set of rules that are shown by SonarLint for VS? How?
A similar question was already asked in [Is there some graphical way to create my own configuration file on SonarLint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298050/is-there-some-graphical-way-to-create-my-own-configuration-file-on-sonarlint) but I wasn't able to follow the answer, i.e. did not find the Project/References/Analyzers node in the Solution Explorer, to be able to edit the active rule set file. Can you help me out on this one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how to open the active rule set of a project:

[image: How to open Active Rule Set from Solution Explorer in VS2015]

From there, you'll be able to enable and disable rules:

[image: Toogle rules in VS2015]

The path to the rule set file to be used is saved within your .csproj file under the `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>...</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` tag. You can reference the same rule set file from multiple projects, and store the rule set along with your project sources in Git / TFVC if you'd like all developers to share the same rule set.

Comment: This is an essential feature of SonarLint, yet it is not mentioned in text anywhere on the SonarLint webpage. It would be good if there would be a "how to get started" on sonarlint.org/visualstudio, or even in the Github README.MD.

Comment: Agreed. I've never seen such a lack of useful information on any tool. Here's a tag <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>. Dude that's wonderful, and I appreciate the time taken to answer. Follow up questions: 1. Does that tag need to be under some other tag? 2. What goes inside the tag?

Comment: How can I do this in IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: @EswaraReddy were you able to find how to do it on IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It looks like you can configure this in IntelliJ IDEA under Settings -> SonarLint

Comment: How to configure this per a project-specific, editor-agnostic config file?