# Can I configure the used ruleset for SonarLint in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

Is there any way to enable/disable rules for SonarLint analysis inside Eclipse? 
I'm using SonarQube Server 5.6 and the Eclipse SonarLint Plugin 2.1 and i can see the rule set on the SQ Server. 
But I would like to edit the rule set locally in my Eclipse IDE. Do anyone know how to achieve this?

This question is similar to this one: [Can I configure the used ruleset for SonarLint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33081197/can-i-configure-the-used-ruleset-for-sonarlint/38435909), but i could not found any solution in Eclipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible.

The only way to change the default quality profile is to connect Eclipse's project to a SonarQube project.